# What is causing compile error in the code?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a VBA loop that will apply a 3 color scale row-by-row to a large table, but am receiving a Compile Error: Invalid or Unqualified Error. I have looked across the forum for answers but am struggling to identify the issue with my code.

```
  Sub AddColorScale()
Dim r As Long

With ActiveSheet
    With Range("BG7:DF466", "BG477:DF971")
        .FormatConditions.Delete
        .FormatConditions.AddColorScale ColorScaleType:=3
        .FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
        .FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(1).Type = xlConditionValueLowestValue
        .FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(1).FormatColor.Color = RGB(248, 105, 107)
    End With
        .FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(2).Type = xlConditionValueNumber
        .FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(2).Value = 0
        .FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(2).FormatColor.Color = RGB(255, 235, 132)
    End With
    With .FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(3).Type = xlConditionValueHighestValue
        .FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(3).FormatColor.Color = RGB(99, 190, 123)
    End With

    For r = 8 To 466 Step 2
        .Range("BG" & r & ":DF" & r).FormatConditions.Delete
    Next r

End With


End Sub
```

Comment: What's with the extra `End With`?

Comment: [Indentation](http://rubberduckvba.com/indentation) helps see the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Will do the errand...

```
With ActiveSheet
    With Range("BG7:DF466", "BG477:DF971")
        .FormatConditions.Delete
        .FormatConditions.AddColorScale ColorScaleType:=3
        .FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
        .FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(1).Type = xlConditionValueLowestValue
        .FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(1).FormatColor.Color = RGB(248, 105, 107)

    'THIS END WITH PROBABLY SHOULDN'T BE HERE
    End With

    'NO RANGE QUALIFICATION, JUST SHEET QUALIFICATION
    .FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(2).Type = xlConditionValueNumber
    .FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(2).Value = 0
    .FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(2).FormatColor.Color = RGB(255, 235, 132)
End With

'I DON'T KNOW WHAT YOU'RE DOING IN THIS WITH... FOO = BAR DOES NOT BELONG
With .FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(3).Type = xlConditionValueHighestValue
    .FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(3).FormatColor.Color = RGB(99, 190, 123)
End With

'NO QUALIFICATIONS
For r = 8 To 466 Step 2
   .Range("BG" & r & ":DF" & r).FormatConditions.Delete
Next r

'EXTRA END WITH
End With
```

At least two errors, one with the qualifications (fix your `with` statements) and the other with misuse of a `with` statement.